# How do determine if drop was exactly with right mouse button up?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

I implemented simple wpf drag and drop and it works good with left or right mouse button. But how can I determine  if drop was exactly with the right mouse button?
My drag'n'drop begins with DragDrop.DoDragDrop and ends with

```
private void OnDropChannelsCommand(DragEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

e.KeyStates is allways DragDropKeyStates.None.

Comment: `Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed` but you need to handle it on the begin drag or drag enter event, and store the state in a variable you can access later. Same with `Mouse.RightButton` for the right one.

Comment: In your DragEnter event handler you decided how to drag by assigning the e.Effects property.  Use that property in your Drop event handler.

Comment: See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/16d1d0f7-5fa5-4845-a836-dab01aa575be/dodragdrop-oddity-with-right-mouse-button?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I end up with handling DragEnter event with

```
e.KeyStates == DragDropKeyStates.RightMouseButton
```

check. Mouse.RightButton was set to Released for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The last point to determinate mouse buttons is DragOver event.

You can then use something like:

```
if ((e.KeyState & 32) == 32) { bool alt = true; }
if ((e.KeyState & 16) == 16) { bool mousebuttonmiddle = true; }
if ((e.KeyState & 8) == 8) { bool control = true; }
if ((e.KeyState & 4) == 4) { bool shift = true; }
if ((e.KeyState & 2) == 2) { bool mousebutton2 = true; }
if ((e.KeyState & 1) == 1) { bool mousebutton1 = true; }
```

To check what is what, and determinate e.Effect at your desired value.
Then you can decide what to do within OnDrop event usung the just previously modified e.Effect.